# Data download failed when trying to download data from S3 bucket in SageMaker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, github-actions, amazon-sagemaker

I am using a GithubActions workflow to run a training job on SageMaker. In my workflow, I use a step as follows to configure my AWS credentials and assume a defined AWS role, let's call it `MyRole`:

```
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_ARN }} # corresponds to MyRole
          role-session-name: GithubActionsName
```

The access key ID and secret access key correspond to a defined user, let's call him `MyUser`.

The workflow step outputs is `Authenticated as assumedRoleId AROA2UC3BBCJG72RJMOFZ:GithubActionsName`, which looks good. It also says I should switch to OpenID Connect Authentication, but that's gonna be for later.

It then manages to start a SageMaker TrainingJob, with an `Estimator` getting a custom Docker training image from my DockerHub registry (I did set `training_repository_access_mode='Vpc'` to that effect and provided my default AWS VPC `subnet_id` and `security_group_id`, I don't know if that might be an error explanation). On SageMaker console I get the following TrainingJob error:

```
ClientError: Data download failed:Failed to download data. ListObjectsV2 failed for s3://my-bucket/path/to/data.txt, nextToken:[null]: Unable to execute request to S3
```

The affiliated IAM role ARN displayed in the Job settings corresponds to the one I mentioned earlier:
`arn:aws:iam::my_account_id:role/MyRole`.
Also, the ARN of the job mentions that the region is the one of the `my-bucket` S3 Bucket.

Moreover, the `MyRole` role has the following permissions: `AdministratorAccess`, `AmazonS3FullAccess`, `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess`, with a trust policy that looks like that :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::my_account_id:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::my_account_id:user/MyUser"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand then why my SageMaker instance that assumes the correct `MyRole` role, in the same region as my bucket cannot access my bucket and download the data. I also tried with AWS CLI locally, temporarily assuming `MyRole` via `MyUser`, and I successfully downloaded the `s3://my-bucket/path/to/data.txt`.

I don't know where should I investigate more the reason of the S3 access fail in my SageMaker TrainingJob, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you have a VPC config added to your Training Job, your VPC networking needs to be properly configured.

1. Do you have a route out to the internet to hit S3 in your VPC? I.e SageMaker will launch ENIs in the subnet(s) provided. They will have Private IPs. Hence, you would need a NAT to break out to the internet.
2. If you do not have a route to the internet for the Training Job to hit S3 then you will need an [S3 Gateway endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html).
   You also need to make sure there is no restrictive resource policy on the VPC endpoint.

It would be good to test launching the Job without the VPC config and noting the behavior. Without the VPC config SageMaker will use the SageMaker managed VPC to hit S3.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for your time! My default VPC not having a defined gateway endpoint, it indeed could not access my S3. It tried with a TensorFlow SageMaker estimator that doesn't require VPC, and I do not get the S3 access error anymore. I will have a look at S3 Gateway endpoint config